# electron-spectron webdriverIO how to get a video tag source?

Tags: mocha.js, electron, webdriver-io, spectron

I am now write some tests with electron-spectron.

After spectrum start my app, I want to check if my video is stopped or not

the code is like

element

```
<video muted autoplay id='videoContainer' class='video'></video>
```

test code

```
.given("",function(){
    //do something
})
.when("",function(){
    //do something
})
.then("the player should stop the program", function() {

    return app.client.someFuncton('//*[@id="videoContainer"]')
        .then(result=>{
            console.log(result)  // suppose to get my video source
        })
})
```

It seems that webdriverIO doesn't have an API like getElementById that I can use to find my video tag's source.

Do someone have any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/selectors.html) for selector in WEBDRIVERIO.

If you want to select an object with id or classname you need to use your selector parameters like below.

**'#' means you are looking for element with id.**

app.client.someFunction('#yourElementsId')

**'.' means you are looking for element with class.**

app.client.someFunction('.yourElementsClassname')